# Split Name into Last name, First Name, Middle Name in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a record below. I want to split the name into Lname, Fname, Mname

```
Name
John, David Handsome
```

Here is my query. I was able to get Lname but not Fname and Mname yet.

```
SELECT 
NAME, 
LEFT(NAME,CHARINDEX(',',NAME)-1)    AS LNAME
FROM TABLE
```

My desired output would be:

```
Name                    Lname   Fname   Mname
John, David Handsome    John    Daivd   Handsome
```

Comment: what DBMS are you using

Comment: What if it is a Latin name like : `Iván De Luca Di Natale` or a French: `Isaac De la Croix` or `Maurits-jan Kuipers op den Kollenstaart`? How do you get the mid name?

Comment: very good question @ Daniel

Comment: I am using SQL sever. The name field is a very common name. No Latin or French names, ect, ect. Thanks

Comment: which version of SQL?

Comment: Julia Louis-Dreyfus, Ronald McDonald, Conan O'Brien and Carl van der Walt, are these also too strange?

Comment: SQL sever version 7

Comment: @joe You need to includ in your question a good sample to work on it

Comment: @joe He mean what is the result when you run this query `SELECT @@VERSION`

Answer (score 0):

If the format of name is gonna remain the same then use below :

```
select name,LEFT(NAME,CHARINDEX(',',NAME)-1)    AS LNAME, regexp_substr(name,'[^ ]+',1,2)  as fname,regexp_substr(name,'[^ ]+',1,3) mname from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this;

```
SELECT 
LEFT(NAME,CHARINDEX(',',NAME)-1) AS LNAME,
LEFT(REPLACE(NAME,LEFT(NAME,CHARINDEX(',',NAME)+1),''),CHARINDEX(' ',REPLACE(NAME,LEFT(NAME,CHARINDEX(',',NAME)+1),''))-1) AS FNAME,
REPLACE(REPLACE(NAME,LEFT(NAME,CHARINDEX(',',NAME)+1),''),LEFT(REPLACE(NAME,LEFT(NAME,CHARINDEX(',',NAME)+1),''),CHARINDEX(' ',REPLACE(NAME,LEFT(NAME,CHARINDEX(',',NAME)+1),''))-1),'') AS MNAME
```

It comes little confusing because of nested replace and charindex functions. But if you focus on them closely, logic is quite simple.